# Specifying PagedListPager options

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, razor-pages, pagedlist

I have the below code for a PagedListPager:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
    model,
    page => Url.Action("Index",
    new
    {
        page,
        sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
        currentFilter = viewBag.CurrentFilter
    }
    ),
    new PagedListRenderOptions()
    {
        LiElementClasses = new List<string> {"myClass", "yourClass"}
    })
```

Within the PagedListRenderOptions instance, how can I specify/add the option for `PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime`?

---

PagedListRenderOptions class is defined as below:

```
public class PagedListRenderOptions
{
    public PagedListRenderOptions();
    ...
    public static PagedListRenderOptions OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime { get; }
    public IEnumerable<string> LiElementClasses { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

The reason why I think this is possible is because the below is possible and works:

```
Html.PagedListPager(
    model,
    page => Url.Action("Index",
    new
    {
        page,
        sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
        currentFilter = viewBag.CurrentFilter
    }
    ),PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)
```

Comment: I know `OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime` is declared as static and without a setter. But surely there is a way to pass it in as an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is declared as a `static` field, and it is not intended to be set.

It just returns a read-only `PagedListRenderOptions` for you with fixed properties so you don't need to create one.

You can use the following

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
model,
page => Url.Action("Index",
new
{
    page,
    sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
    currentFilter = viewBag.CurrentFilter
}
),
new PagedListRenderOptions()
{
    LiElementClasses = new List<string> {"myClass", "yourClass"},
    //The following properties are the same as OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime
    DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Never,
    DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Never,
    DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
    DisplayLinkToNextPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
    MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 5
})
```

**Consider a similar case.**

You can construct a `Color` structure by setting its A,R,G,B value. When you need a blue color, however, you can just use [Color.Blue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.blue?view=netframework-4.7.2) which is a static, read-only property, its A,R,G,B values are fixed and already set for you.

Comment: Makes sense, I totally understand that, but for some reason you can pass that property as an option in the PagedListPager initialiser. See my update. But you are right from the looks of it, doesn't seem possible with the way I'm hoping for...

Comment: Ok, so I think we are aligned. You can try to declare a variable ‘var option = PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime;’, and add additional properties to the variable. And then pass this variable to the method. But just can’t do this in one line.

Comment: I have already implement similar to what you have in the answer, with some element classes. This is the best way.